# How to limit methods in 'Allow' header when the request is of OPTIONS type?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, http-headers

So, this is in the CORS filter class.

```
// Authorize (allow) all domains to consume the content
    ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", values.isEmpty()?"*":values);
    ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST");
    ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*");

    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    // For HTTP OPTIONS verb/method reply with ACCEPTED status code -- per CORS handshake
    /*if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
                    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
        return;
    }*/

    resp.addHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1");
    resp.addHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000");
    resp.addHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'");
    resp.addHeader("X-WebKit-CSP", "default-src 'self'");
    resp.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
    resp.addHeader("Referrer-Policy", "no-referrer");

    String origin = request.getHeader("origin");
     if(origin!=null && !values.isEmpty()) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(values.split(" , ")));
    if(!list.contains(origin)) {
         ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
         System.out.println("Entered origin check");
         return;
    }
     }
```

When I change the request of an API to OPTIONS, the 'Allow' header shows all these
[options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYvob.jpg) i.e. GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH

I want it to be restricted to only GET, POST when sending an OPTIONS request.

Comment: Allow header is sent to indicate the possible methods we can use for a specific resource, if you restrict it to GET and POST it indicates that even OPTIONS are not supported which is not the case. As for CORS, the Access-Control-Allow-Methods shows the desired methods (GET and POST)

Comment: That's exactly what I've been asked to do. It's a vulnerability thing. So it has to be GET and POST

Comment: No it's not a vulnerability, this headers are there to just give information, some browsers don't implement them all or don't even care about it. Even if you use CORS, http clients other than browsers can call your endpoints without any problem.